# ssh hangs if interrupted in the middle

Tags: linux, shell, ssh

The following code suppose to print "connected" repeatedly if ssh is able to connect to the remote machine, else "not-connected" will be printed.

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ "1" ]
do
    ifconfig usb0 &>/dev/null
    if [ "$(echo $?)" == "0" ]
    then
        sshpass -p passwd ssh -o ConnectTimeout=5 duser@10.1.1.3 sudo echo "connected"
    else
        echo "not-connected"
    fi
    sleep 0.2
done
```

The remote machine is connected via the usb0 interface. I am testing this script by frequently unplugging and plugging the usb interface. The problem is sometimes when i unplug the usb interfaces, the code stuck at ssh and it is not printing repeatedly. I suppose if ssh is interrupted in the middle of executing it is getting stuck. How can i overcome this ? Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Most apparently its not hanging at all. 
But the way you are printing connected seems like wrong.

This looks pretty much suspicious

`sshpass -p passwd ssh -o ConnectTimeout=5 duser@10.1.1.3 sudo grep "connected"`

What are you trying to grep ?

Normally if you need to grep the output of some app you need to do it via pipe e.g.

`ls | grep "connected"`

Comment: It is echo "connected" not grep. I have edited. Sorry for that

Comment: again its still wrong, what are you trying to execute on remote host ?

Comment: My remote host is a Cohda DSRC modem running a ubuntu os. I am checking the status of  "sudo llc rxphylast" command, which will result the RSSI value of the modem. To avoid all those complexity, i have just put an echo command.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `bash`, this is a much better way to do your test:

```
2>/dev/null >/dev/tcp/<ip_addr>/<port> && echo pass || echo fail
```

For more details, see the Bash documentation on [redirections](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections).